# How do I animate a certain part of an SVG with CSS3?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, animate.css, svg-animate

I am not too familiar with animating SVG's embedded within HTML but here's what I attempted to do.

I have one SVG image on my site like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 125 219.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 125 219.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#735545;}
.st1{fill:#5C4033;}
.st2{fill:none;}
.st3{fill:#3E3E48;}
.st4{fill:#2D2E39;}
.st5{fill:#BAB9B5;}
.st6{fill:#A3A2A1;}
.st7{fill:#CFCDC6;}
.st8{fill:#E0E0DC;}
.st9{fill:#E64D3C;}
.st10{fill:#CC3E36;}
.st11{fill:#C9C3BB;}
.st12{fill:#B0A79A;}
.st13{fill:#B5AEA4;}
.st14{fill:#E1CBB9;}
.st15{fill:#CDAE98;}
.st16{fill:#CB8E7E;}
.st17{fill:#B27669;}
.st18{fill:#393631;}
.st19{fill:#484642;}
.st20{fill:#F0C419;}
.st21{fill:#F29D1F;}
.st22{fill:#E57E25;}
.st23{fill:#D15627;}
.st24{fill:#C03B2B;}
</style>
<title>molay</title>
<g>
<g>
    <g>
        <polygon class="st0" points="37.5,8.7 37.5,201.1 61.8,201.1 61.8,0          "/>
        <polygon class="st1" points="61.8,0 61.8,201.1 86.2,201.1 86.2,7.6          "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st2" points="94,86.4 67.5,98.1 61.8,100.6 86.2,89.8                 "/>
            <polygon class="st3" points="53,74.6 35.9,81.9 29.7,86.4 56.2,98.1 61.8,100.6 61.8,75.8                 "/>
            <polygon class="st4" points="94,86.4 87.8,81.9 70.7,74.6 61.8,75.8 61.8,100.6 67.5,98.1                 "/>
            <polygon class="st5" points="103.3,102.3 94,86.4 86.2,89.8 86.2,141.2 100,128.6                 "/>
            <polygon class="st6" points="29.7,86.4 20.5,102.3 23.7,128.6 37.5,141.2 37.5,89.8               "/>
            <polygon class="st7" points="57.7,133.5 55.6,133.5 58.1,131.8 59.7,128.6 59.8,121.3 52.5,121.4 49.3,123 47.6,125.5 
                47.6,123.4 47.6,119.2 47.6,115.1 47.6,113 49.3,115.4 52.5,117.1 59.8,117.2 59.7,109.9 58.1,106.7 55.6,104.9 57.7,104.9 
                61.8,104.9 61.8,100.6 37.5,89.8 37.5,141.2 37.5,166.6 61.8,175.4 61.8,133.5                 "/>
            <polygon class="st8" points="61.8,100.6 61.8,104.9 61.9,104.9 66,104.9 68.1,104.9 65.7,106.7 64,109.9 63.9,117.2 71.2,117.1 
                74.4,115.4 76.1,113 76.1,115.1 76.1,119.2 76.1,123.4 76.1,125.5 74.4,123 71.2,121.4 63.9,121.3 64,128.6 65.7,131.8 
                68.1,133.5 66,133.5 61.9,133.5 61.8,133.5 61.8,175.4 86.2,166.6 86.2,141.2 86.2,89.8                "/>
            <polygon class="st9" points="55.6,104.9 58.1,106.7 59.7,109.9 59.8,117.2 52.5,117.1 49.3,115.4 47.6,113 47.6,115.1 
                47.6,119.2 47.6,123.4 47.6,125.5 49.3,123 52.5,121.4 59.8,121.3 59.7,128.6 58.1,131.8 55.6,133.5 57.7,133.5 61.8,133.5 
                61.8,104.9 57.7,104.9               "/>
            <polygon class="st10" points="61.9,133.5 66,133.5 68.1,133.5 65.7,131.8 64,128.6 63.9,121.3 71.2,121.4 74.4,123 76.1,125.5 
                76.1,123.4 76.1,119.2 76.1,115.1 76.1,113 74.4,115.4 71.2,117.1 63.9,117.2 64,109.9 65.7,106.7 68.1,104.9 66,104.9 
                61.9,104.9 61.8,104.9 61.8,133.5                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <polygon class="st11" points="81.6,72.8 81.6,65.9 78.1,59.3 78.1,54.7 74.4,43.8 61.8,43.8 61.8,84.1 62.8,88.6 65.4,89.8 
                        69.1,87.9 70.2,83.1 70.2,74.8 84.5,80.5                         "/>
                    <polygon class="st12" points="53.5,83.1 54.6,87.9 53.5,83.1                         "/>
                    <polygon class="st13" points="49.3,43.8 45.7,54.7 45.7,59.3 42.1,65.9 42.1,72.8 39.2,80.5 53.5,74.8 53.5,83.1 54.6,87.9 
                        58.3,89.8 60.9,88.6 61.8,84.1 61.8,43.8                         "/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <polygon class="st14" points="71.2,40.3 74.4,43.8 74.4,48.3 72.9,55.3 72.7,59.3 69,67.6 69,67.6 72.7,59.2 72.9,55.2 
                        74.4,48.2 74.4,43.7                         "/>
                    <path class="st14" d="M55.8,38.5l-3.4,1.7l-3.2,3.6v4.5l1.5,7l0.2,4l3.7,8.4c0,0,4.5-3,4.6-3l2.6-0.1V37.3L55.8,38.5z"/>
                    <path class="st15" d="M72.9,55.3l1.5-7v-4.5l-3.1-3.5l-3.4-1.7l-6-1.2v27.3v0.1l2.6,0.1c0.2,0,4.5,2.9,4.5,2.9l0-0.1l3.7-8.3
                        L72.9,55.3z"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <polygon class="st16" points="59.2,64.7 61.8,66.8 64.5,64.7 61.8,59.4                   "/>
                <polygon class="st17" points="61.8,59.4 59.2,64.7 61.8,66.8 61.8,66.8                   "/>
                <polygon class="st18" points="52.6,52.4 53.5,51.3 58.6,49.3 59.7,50.1                   "/>
                <polygon class="st19" points="56.1,55.5 54.5,55.1 55.1,54.4 57,54.4 57.7,55.1                   "/>
                <polygon class="st19" points="67.6,55.4 66.1,55 66.7,54.3 68.6,54.3 69.2,55                     "/>
                <polygon class="st18" points="71.1,52.4 70.2,51.3 65.1,49.3 64,50.1                     "/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
   </g>

   <g>



     <g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st20" points="50,141.8 53.2,131.6 37.7,138.8 45.4,155.8 37.3,163.5 30.8,159 29.2,145.6 0,144.3 17.3,155.8 
                11.2,174.4 25.3,203.7 61.6,214.9 61.6,155.8                 "/>

            <polygon class="st21" points="123.3,144.3 94.1,145.6 92.5,159 85.9,163.5 77.8,155.8 85.6,138.8 70.1,131.6 73.2,141.8 
                61.6,155.8 61.6,214.9 98,203.7 112.1,174.4 106,155.8                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st22" points="50,146 53.2,135.8 37.7,142.9 45.4,159.9 37.3,167.6 30.8,163.2 29.2,149.8 0,148.4 17.3,159.9 
                11.2,178.6 25.3,207.9 61.6,219.1 61.6,159.9                 "/>
            <polygon class="st23" points="123.3,148.4 94.1,149.8 92.5,163.2 85.9,167.6 77.8,159.9 85.6,142.9 70.1,135.8 73.2,146 
                61.6,159.9 61.6,219.1 98,207.9 112.1,178.6 106,159.9                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st9" points="54,171 56.1,164.3 45.9,169 51,180.1 45.7,185.2 41.4,182.3 40.3,173.5 21.1,172.6 32.5,180.1 
                28.4,192.4 37.7,211.7 61.6,219.1 61.6,180.1                 "/>
            <polygon class="st24" points="102.2,172.6 83,173.5 81.9,182.3 77.6,185.2 72.3,180.1 77.4,169 67.2,164.3 69.3,171 61.6,180.1 
                61.6,219.1 85.6,211.7 94.8,192.4 90.8,180.1                 "/>
        </g>
    </g>




    <polygon class="st21" points="107.6,135.1 125,128.1 107.6,131.3         "/>
    <polygon class="st20" points="17.4,135.1 0,128.1 17.4,131.3         "/>
    <polygon class="st20" points="10.8,122.9 13.8,126.6 15.6,122.9      "/>
    <polygon class="st21" points="112.3,122.9 109.3,126.6 107.6,122.9       "/>
</g>
```

I tried to animate some sections within the 'g' brackets using animate.css. So I would wrap them around a...

```
 <section class="wow animated fadeInLeft"> 
 </section>
```

But it wasn't working so obviously I am doing it completely wrong. I want a certain section of the .svg to start pulsing (so zooming in and out infinitely). The following section...

```
        <g>
          <g>
            <polygon class="st20" points="50,141.8 53.2,131.6 37.7,138.8 45.4,155.8 37.3,163.5 30.8,159 29.2,145.6 0,144.3 17.3,155.8 
                11.2,174.4 25.3,203.7 61.6,214.9 61.6,155.8                 "/>

            <polygon class="st21" points="123.3,144.3 94.1,145.6 92.5,159 85.9,163.5 77.8,155.8 85.6,138.8 70.1,131.6 73.2,141.8 
                61.6,155.8 61.6,214.9 98,203.7 112.1,174.4 106,155.8                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st22" points="50,146 53.2,135.8 37.7,142.9 45.4,159.9 37.3,167.6 30.8,163.2 29.2,149.8 0,148.4 17.3,159.9 
                11.2,178.6 25.3,207.9 61.6,219.1 61.6,159.9                 "/>
            <polygon class="st23" points="123.3,148.4 94.1,149.8 92.5,163.2 85.9,167.6 77.8,159.9 85.6,142.9 70.1,135.8 73.2,146 
                61.6,159.9 61.6,219.1 98,207.9 112.1,178.6 106,159.9                "/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <polygon class="st9" points="54,171 56.1,164.3 45.9,169 51,180.1 45.7,185.2 41.4,182.3 40.3,173.5 21.1,172.6 32.5,180.1 
                28.4,192.4 37.7,211.7 61.6,219.1 61.6,180.1                 "/>
            <polygon class="st24" points="102.2,172.6 83,173.5 81.9,182.3 77.6,185.2 72.3,180.1 77.4,169 67.2,164.3 69.3,171 61.6,180.1 
                61.6,219.1 85.6,211.7 94.8,192.4 90.8,180.1                 "/>
        </g>
    </g>
```

What code can I implement to make that part of the svg group to pulse in and out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add any wrapper elements at all. Just add the animate.css specific classes to the wrapper `g` element like in the below snippet and it would work.

One additional thing that you need to do is to set the `transform-origin` for the animated `g` element. I've set it as the bottom-right point based on the coords of the `g` elements.

```css
.animated {
  transform-origin: 61.6px 219.1px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 125 219.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 125 219.1;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #735545;
    }
    .st1 {
      fill: #5C4033;
    }
    .st2 {
      fill: none;
    }
    .st3 {
      fill: #3E3E48;
    }
    .st4 {
      fill: #2D2E39;
    }
    .st5 {
      fill: #BAB9B5;
    }
    .st6 {
      fill: #A3A2A1;
    }
    .st7 {
      fill: #CFCDC6;
    }
    .st8 {
      fill: #E0E0DC;
    }
    .st9 {
      fill: #E64D3C;
    }
    .st10 {
      fill: #CC3E36;
    }
    .st11 {
      fill: #C9C3BB;
    }
    .st12 {
      fill: #B0A79A;
    }
    .st13 {
      fill: #B5AEA4;
    }
    .st14 {
      fill: #E1CBB9;
    }
    .st15 {
      fill: #CDAE98;
    }
    .st16 {
      fill: #CB8E7E;
    }
    .st17 {
      fill: #B27669;
    }
    .st18 {
      fill: #393631;
    }
    .st19 {
      fill: #484642;
    }
    .st20 {
      fill: #F0C419;
    }
    .st21 {
      fill: #F29D1F;
    }
    .st22 {
      fill: #E57E25;
    }
    .st23 {
      fill: #D15627;
    }
    .st24 {
      fill: #C03B2B;
    }
  </style>
  <title>molay</title>
  <g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <polygon class="st0" points="37.5,8.7 37.5,201.1 61.8,201.1 61.8,0          " />
        <polygon class="st1" points="61.8,0 61.8,201.1 86.2,201.1 86.2,7.6          " />
      </g>
      <g>
        <g>
          <polygon class="st2" points="94,86.4 67.5,98.1 61.8,100.6 86.2,89.8                 " />
          <polygon class="st3" points="53,74.6 35.9,81.9 29.7,86.4 56.2,98.1 61.8,100.6 61.8,75.8                 " />
          <polygon class="st4" points="94,86.4 87.8,81.9 70.7,74.6 61.8,75.8 61.8,100.6 67.5,98.1                 " />
          <polygon class="st5" points="103.3,102.3 94,86.4 86.2,89.8 86.2,141.2 100,128.6                 " />
          <polygon class="st6" points="29.7,86.4 20.5,102.3 23.7,128.6 37.5,141.2 37.5,89.8               " />
          <polygon class="st7" points="57.7,133.5 55.6,133.5 58.1,131.8 59.7,128.6 59.8,121.3 52.5,121.4 49.3,123 47.6,125.5 
                47.6,123.4 47.6,119.2 47.6,115.1 47.6,113 49.3,115.4 52.5,117.1 59.8,117.2 59.7,109.9 58.1,106.7 55.6,104.9 57.7,104.9 
                61.8,104.9 61.8,100.6 37.5,89.8 37.5,141.2 37.5,166.6 61.8,175.4 61.8,133.5                 " />
          <polygon class="st8" points="61.8,100.6 61.8,104.9 61.9,104.9 66,104.9 68.1,104.9 65.7,106.7 64,109.9 63.9,117.2 71.2,117.1 
                74.4,115.4 76.1,113 76.1,115.1 76.1,119.2 76.1,123.4 76.1,125.5 74.4,123 71.2,121.4 63.9,121.3 64,128.6 65.7,131.8 
                68.1,133.5 66,133.5 61.9,133.5 61.8,133.5 61.8,175.4 86.2,166.6 86.2,141.2 86.2,89.8                " />
          <polygon class="st9" points="55.6,104.9 58.1,106.7 59.7,109.9 59.8,117.2 52.5,117.1 49.3,115.4 47.6,113 47.6,115.1 
                47.6,119.2 47.6,123.4 47.6,125.5 49.3,123 52.5,121.4 59.8,121.3 59.7,128.6 58.1,131.8 55.6,133.5 57.7,133.5 61.8,133.5 
                61.8,104.9 57.7,104.9               " />
          <polygon class="st10" points="61.9,133.5 66,133.5 68.1,133.5 65.7,131.8 64,128.6 63.9,121.3 71.2,121.4 74.4,123 76.1,125.5 
                76.1,123.4 76.1,119.2 76.1,115.1 76.1,113 74.4,115.4 71.2,117.1 63.9,117.2 64,109.9 65.7,106.7 68.1,104.9 66,104.9 
                61.9,104.9 61.8,104.9 61.8,133.5                " />
        </g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <g>
              <polygon class="st11" points="81.6,72.8 81.6,65.9 78.1,59.3 78.1,54.7 74.4,43.8 61.8,43.8 61.8,84.1 62.8,88.6 65.4,89.8 
                        69.1,87.9 70.2,83.1 70.2,74.8 84.5,80.5                         " />
              <polygon class="st12" points="53.5,83.1 54.6,87.9 53.5,83.1                         " />
              <polygon class="st13" points="49.3,43.8 45.7,54.7 45.7,59.3 42.1,65.9 42.1,72.8 39.2,80.5 53.5,74.8 53.5,83.1 54.6,87.9 
                        58.3,89.8 60.9,88.6 61.8,84.1 61.8,43.8                         " />
            </g>
            <g>
              <polygon class="st14" points="71.2,40.3 74.4,43.8 74.4,48.3 72.9,55.3 72.7,59.3 69,67.6 69,67.6 72.7,59.2 72.9,55.2 
                        74.4,48.2 74.4,43.7                         " />
              <path class="st14" d="M55.8,38.5l-3.4,1.7l-3.2,3.6v4.5l1.5,7l0.2,4l3.7,8.4c0,0,4.5-3,4.6-3l2.6-0.1V37.3L55.8,38.5z" />
              <path class="st15" d="M72.9,55.3l1.5-7v-4.5l-3.1-3.5l-3.4-1.7l-6-1.2v27.3v0.1l2.6,0.1c0.2,0,4.5,2.9,4.5,2.9l0-0.1l3.7-8.3
                        L72.9,55.3z" />
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
            <polygon class="st16" points="59.2,64.7 61.8,66.8 64.5,64.7 61.8,59.4                   " />
            <polygon class="st17" points="61.8,59.4 59.2,64.7 61.8,66.8 61.8,66.8                   " />
            <polygon class="st18" points="52.6,52.4 53.5,51.3 58.6,49.3 59.7,50.1                   " />
            <polygon class="st19" points="56.1,55.5 54.5,55.1 55.1,54.4 57,54.4 57.7,55.1                   " />
            <polygon class="st19" points="67.6,55.4 66.1,55 66.7,54.3 68.6,54.3 69.2,55                     " />
            <polygon class="st18" points="71.1,52.4 70.2,51.3 65.1,49.3 64,50.1                     " />
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>

    <g>



      <g class='animated pulse'>
        <g>
          <polygon class="st20" points="50,141.8 53.2,131.6 37.7,138.8 45.4,155.8 37.3,163.5 30.8,159 29.2,145.6 0,144.3 17.3,155.8 
                11.2,174.4 25.3,203.7 61.6,214.9 61.6,155.8                 " />

          <polygon class="st21" points="123.3,144.3 94.1,145.6 92.5,159 85.9,163.5 77.8,155.8 85.6,138.8 70.1,131.6 73.2,141.8 
                61.6,155.8 61.6,214.9 98,203.7 112.1,174.4 106,155.8                " />
        </g>
        <g>
          <polygon class="st22" points="50,146 53.2,135.8 37.7,142.9 45.4,159.9 37.3,167.6 30.8,163.2 29.2,149.8 0,148.4 17.3,159.9 
                11.2,178.6 25.3,207.9 61.6,219.1 61.6,159.9                 " />
          <polygon class="st23" points="123.3,148.4 94.1,149.8 92.5,163.2 85.9,167.6 77.8,159.9 85.6,142.9 70.1,135.8 73.2,146 
                61.6,159.9 61.6,219.1 98,207.9 112.1,178.6 106,159.9                " />
        </g>
        <g>
          <polygon class="st9" points="54,171 56.1,164.3 45.9,169 51,180.1 45.7,185.2 41.4,182.3 40.3,173.5 21.1,172.6 32.5,180.1 
                28.4,192.4 37.7,211.7 61.6,219.1 61.6,180.1                 " />
          <polygon class="st24" points="102.2,172.6 83,173.5 81.9,182.3 77.6,185.2 72.3,180.1 77.4,169 67.2,164.3 69.3,171 61.6,180.1 
                61.6,219.1 85.6,211.7 94.8,192.4 90.8,180.1                 " />
        </g>
      </g>




      <polygon class="st21" points="107.6,135.1 125,128.1 107.6,131.3         " />
      <polygon class="st20" points="17.4,135.1 0,128.1 17.4,131.3         " />
      <polygon class="st20" points="10.8,122.9 13.8,126.6 15.6,122.9      " />
      <polygon class="st21" points="112.3,122.9 109.3,126.6 107.6,122.9       " />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Impressed by your SVG skills. Can you please share some documentation or study material if available to learn SVG. I understand other tags except PATH tag.

Comment: santhoshoct14@gmail.com is my mailing ID

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: The only reference that I use for SVGs is the MDN. Here is the link to a [MDN tutor on Path tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Comment: @Harry oh very interesting, that makes sense, I see now. Thanks for the help.